# The phone has a case in flowers

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> The phone has **a case in flowers**.

Is the sentence correct or should I change it? (I mean the picture of flowers, that the case is covered with flowers.)

It seems to me strange and I would change it into:

> The phone case has **flowers**.

What's your opinion on that? Is the sentence in my question correct?

Comment: You should also try to include details about the _meaning_ that you are trying to express.

Comment: ... maybe a picture of this phone? That might be the best way to explain what you want to describe.

Comment: I mean the picture of flowers, that the case is covered with flowers. How to do it correctly?

Comment: @masterkomp You need to incorporate your explanation in the body of your question; there's an Edit button beneath it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is not incorrect, but this is a tricky thing to express.

For example, if you and your friend are both looking at the phone case, you could say:

> ***That phone case is covered in flowers***.

(Note: You could use the preposition *with* instead of *in*; the verb *covered* allows for both.)

One the other hand, if you were describing the phone case via a text message, and the other person couldn't see it, you might want to be a bit more precise, and provide more specific details. After all, we're talking about the picture on the case, not the case itself.

So, we could say:

> ***The phone case has a picture with many flowers***.

---

This can actually be a tricky thing to describe unambiguously. For example, let's say the phone case looks something like this:

[image]

In that case, you could say:

> ***The picture on the phone case has a bunch of flowers***.

This would be correct, but the word *bunch*, when used in conjunction with flowers, might make a person think of a *flower bunch*:

[image]

So, you might instead say:

> ***The picture on the phone case has a flowery pattern***.

but the word *pattern* might make the reader think of something more regular – that is, something more like one of these:

[image]

So it's not going to be easy to say it in a way that isn't prone to some kind of misinterpretation. I might say something like this:

> ***The phone case has a lot of different flowers in a random pattern***.

That is a pretty accurate description, but it took me some effort to come up with that wording. Even then, some might rightly complain that *random pattern* is an oxymoron.

This is something even a native speaker might have to think about to get right.

Comment: The phone cover has a floral design/pattern

Comment: @JavaLatte - Ooooh, I like _floral pattern_! Well-said! If you made that an answer, I'd beg for the O.P. to move the green checkmark.